# computer game in Italian

Tags: vocabulary

What would you call a "computer game" in Italian?

Examples are GTA, Need for Speed etc.

Suggestions: gioco per computer, gioco del computer, videogioco, gioco per PC.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC_game

Thank you.

Comment: I see you are very dedicated to studying in depth Italian lexicon, and this is a very good thing. Have you considered buying a real, full-fledged English-Italian / Italian-English dictionary? It is full of answers to questions like this.

Answer (score 4):

You can say "videogioco" for every kind of "videogame" or "computer game". There isn't an actual word for "computer game" but you can say "videogioco per computer/pc".

Comment: Videogioco per computer suona malissimo. Ed è una ripetizione, perché "videogioco" e "gioco per computer" sono sinonimi

Comment: Videogioco non implica che sia per computer. Un videogioco può anche essere arcade, per console,... Aggiungerei anche che le console non sono computer perchè in quest'ambito per "computer" si intende il "personal computer" e non tutti gli apparecchi elettronici a scopo aritmetico. Inoltre nell'ambito commerciale è raccomandato specificare la piattaforma per il videogioco.

Comment: Tutti i videogiochi sono per computer. Gli arcade sono computer. Le "console" sono computer". Gli smartphone sono computer. "Videogioco per computer" è una ripetizione.

Comment: Studio informatica, so benissimo cos'è un computer e sì, le cose elencate lo sono (a parte gli arcade che sono elaboratori e possono funzionare senza unità aritmetiche) ma, in ambito commerciale devi saper specificare la piattaforma videoludica, tant'è che gli ho detto di tradurlo semplicemente con "videogioco" (leggi la prima frase) e ho poi approfondito con la seconda frase. Al posto di darmi il downvote e darmi anche contro per motivi futili (perché tanto non cambierò la mia risposta) potresti invece rispondere a modo tuo nell'area sottostante.

Comment: "Videogioco per computer" è una traduzione orribile ed imprecisa. Se fosse "videogioco per PC", inteso come "videogioco per Windows" sarebbe accettabile, però davvero non si può sentire.

Comment: Cito: " "videogioco per computer/pc" " e sottolineo "pc". Comunque non è affatto una ripetizione: videogioco sono 2 parole di origine latina (video e iocum), computer deriva dal verbo latino computare. Inoltre se l'unione di vocaboli "videogioco per computer" fosse errato, non dovrei trovare alcun risultato su alcun motore di ricerca, oppure il motore dovrebbe correggermelo, ma questo non accade. Rimango della mia ipotesi e ti invito a rispondere nell'area sottostante a modo tuo anziché continuare a commentare.

Comment: Appunto. "Videogioco per pc" è accetabile e "videogioco per computer" non lo è. Se non vuoi che commentino le tue risposte sei sul sito sbagliato

Comment: Ho eliminato il commento comunque, non ho intenzione di rispondere ulteriormente.

Comment: @Bruno9779 "Videogioco per computer" è una traduzione orribile e allo stesso tempo piuttosto precisa, molto più di "videogioco". L'osservazione che anche arcade, console ecc. sono computer è un arrampicarsi sugli specchi, dato che in quel senso anche un orologio digitale, una calcolatrice e una miriade di altre cose sono computer, e anche dato che ad es. un gioco per una console non gira su computer o arcade ecc. "Videogioco" e "Gioco per computer" non sono assolutamente sinonimi; un gioco per computer è anche un videogioco ma un videogioco non è necessariamente un gioco per computer.

Answer (score 0):

"videogioco" is literally videogame while "videogioco per computer" means computer game.

Answer (score 0):

"Videogioco" is a videogame/computer game.

"Videogioco per computer" is a repetition, sounds horrible and I have never heard it being used in an actual conversation.

It is different when instead of the generic "computer" you say what plattform is it for:

"Videogioco per Linux", " Videogioco per Playstation" etc

Comment: "Videogioco per computer" is not a repetition, a "videogioco" is not necessarily for computers. F.ex. a console game doesn't even work on a computer but it's certainly a videogioco.

Comment: @SantiBailors Consoles ARE computers. There where a few non arithmetic processors used for gaming in the '70s, that is, 4 decades ago. "Videogioco per computer" is unheard of and sounds clunky and a little childish.

Comment: "Videogioco per computer" is maybe unheard of by you, but it is actually a very common expression. It's also the first thing google.it suggests as soon as I type the "c" in "videogioco per c". If you tell your kid "I'm going to give you a videogioco" and he/she replies "For my computer or for my console ?", are you going to correct him/her, or reply "A console is a computer" ? You know what "computer" means in common language, please take that into account, don't play with irrelevant technicalities.